# What is a good name for the following linq extension method?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a few places in my code I want to get a collection of an enumerable with the 1st element, the first 2 elements, the first 3 elements of a collection and so on.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> SomeFunc<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if(source.Any())
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, source.Count()).Select(c => source.Take(c));
    }
    else
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<TSource>>();;
    }
}
```

What is a good name for this function?

Comment: I'd call it `Prefixes<T>()`.

Comment: @Anders Write an answer. As this is *the* answer.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<TSource>>()`?

Comment: @Roman, your function is much more complicated than necessary. You don’t need the `if` at all; the first branch is entirely sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Not a question with a definite correct answer, but as I commented earlier `Prefixes<T>()` is probably a suitable name. Prefixes of a string would be the word prefixes, for example.

```
var x = Prefixes("Dog", 2);
```

Would be the word prefixes `{ "D", "Do" }`.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a name that best describes what the function does. It should be self documenting at all times. So in your case i would suggest something like

```
GetCollectionOfInitialCharacters
```

Comment: If someone passes in a collection of button objects, I would find it a bit odd that the method had the suffix `Characters`.

Comment: I agree - but i was giving a suggestion, not a 100% answer.. Many coding standards suggest using an 'active' naming for a method that performs stuff. For example, not 'Total' but 'CalculateEffectiveRevenue'.